# const in function declaration

Tags: c, arrays

In an array that's declared in a function call as

```
int addTax(const int* anArray, int* pNewArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(anArray)/sizeof(int); i++)
    {
         /* Not important code */  
    }
    return *pNewArray;
}
```

does the `const` in the `const int* anArray` argument guarantee that it is only an input argument, as compared to `*pNewArray` which is a return argument?

Comment: How does that compile?

Comment: `pNewArray` lacks a type.

Comment: All it guarantees is that you cannot write to `*anArray`.  Note that your `sizeof` hack won't work (`anArray` is a pointer in this context, not an array; you won't get the number of array elements).  And yeah, you need a type for `*pNewArray`.

Comment: Is that first line supposed to be `int addTax(const int* anArray, int *pNewArray)`?

Comment: Thanks John, wasn't aware of that. And yes Hurkyl sorry I forgot declare the array point of *pNewArray.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood something, but *how can one create a return argument*??

`const` is used to indicate that the variable marked like this must not be changed. This doesn't work like that when you use pointers, though. One can still change the value of a thing the pointer points to.

*This code is really odd*. You're returning a pointer to `int`, but the function says it returns just an `int`. As it was mentioned in the comments, your code *won't even compile* because of that.

Comment: This book is very confusing... According to what the describes as the result, it should store the new tax value in pNewArray element [i] and then return the address of the new array. :S This book sucks too be honest, not sure why the university decided on this book.

Comment: If `pNewArray` is type `int *`, then `return *pNewArray` does indeed return an `int`, not a pointer to `int`. The code is still very odd and confused, though. "Returning" via an output argument is a well-known technique, but the code that is shown at least does not do that.

Comment: @whitelotus, not sure what book're you talking about. You'd better read a book written by Dennis Ritchie and Brian Kernighan, "The C programming language".

Answer (score 0):

> does the const in the const int* anArray argument guarantee that it is only an input argument

The `const` qualifier here means that the function will not use `anArray` pointer to modify the object it points to.